# visual studio 2013 - how to match specific line with regex?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2013

I want to match a specific line with regex in Visual Studio 2013 and delete the whole line, the first three characters in this kind of line are #, whitespace and a number.
so, how to write the regex to match these lines? thanks!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: As a minor improvement I suggest to add some examples of those lines you want to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match a `#` followed by `whitespace` and then `number`, use:

```
/^\#[\ \t]+\d+.*$/gm
```

You might need global and multi-line modifier.

Using `\s` should be avoided as it matches `\n` and `\r` too.

This will match all those lines that start with `#` followed by whitespace and number.